# Caret package - Logistic regression how to find Pseudo R square

Tags: r, logistic, r-squared, caret

Hi I am interested in utilizing caret for making inferences on a particular data set...  Since this is caret-model, most common methods to find pseudo Rsquare fail.

> model <- train(lg.train.data[,1:15],
>                         lg.train.data[,16], 
>                         method = 'glmStepAIC', 
>                         trControl = objControl,
>                         metric = "ROC",
>                         #preProc = c("center","scale"),
>                         verbose = FALSE)

Is it possible to find the Pseudo R square for the model created using syntax?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you